# Select most recent record based on two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have user1 who exchanged messages with user2 and user4 (these parameters are known). I now want to select the latest sent or received message for each conversation (i.e. LIMIT 1 for each conversation).

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96407/1)**

Currently my query returns all messages for all conversations:

```
SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE (toUserID IN (2,4) AND userID = 1)
OR    (userID IN (2,4) AND toUserID = 1)
ORDER BY message.time DESC
```

The returned rows should be messageID 3 and 6.

Comment: You forgot to add table data. (message 3 and 6...)

Comment: Is it guaranteed that a message with id = 100 will be more newer than the message with id = 99?

Comment: Yes, it actually doesn't matter if I sort for time DESC or messageID DESC.

Comment: I think there is some ambiguity in your question:
Do you need **a)** the latest incoming and the latest outgoing message for **any** of the two conversations (even if they are both in the same conversation) or **b)** the latest message (incoming or outgoing) within each of the conversations?
In the former case Marcus Adams answer is correct, for the latter case, I think, mine is correct.

Comment: I need the latest message (in- or outcoming) within each of the conversations, so your answer is fine. I'll give you a thumbs up, but will probably accept @SalmanA answer, because I do not have to pre-query all the userIDs user 1 has a conversation with and can save 1 query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that higher `id` values indicate more recent messages, you can do this:

- Find all messages that involve user 1
- Group the results by the other user id
- Get the maximum message id per group

```sql
SELECT *
FROM message
WHERE messageID IN (
    SELECT MAX(messageID)
    FROM message
    WHERE userID = 1 -- optionally filter by the other user
    OR toUserID = 1 -- optionally filter by the other user
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN userID = 1 THEN toUserID ELSE userID END
)
ORDER BY messageID DESC
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6962b/1)

Comment: But that assumption can not be made. Even in the example SQLFiddle in the question this assumption is already broken.

Comment: I asked OP about this who says it is OK. If not, query from revision 1 http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28608215/1 can be used.

Comment: I just saw that, but than the OP should maybe update his example ;)

Comment: This looks promising. So I can even save one query to get all the userIDs with which user 1 has a ongoing conversation. Gotta try this when sqlfiddle is running again (this website is so slow :/).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily by separating it into two queries with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` then joining them with `UNION`:

```
(SELECT *
FROM message 
WHERE (toUserID IN (2,4) AND userID = 1)
ORDER BY message.time DESC
LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE (userID IN (2,4) AND toUserID = 1)
ORDER BY message.time DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

The parenthesis are important here, and this returns messages 2 and 6, which seems correct, not 3 and 6.

It also seems like you could use `UNION ALL` for performance instead of `UNION` because there won't be duplicates between the two queries, but it's better if you decide that.

Here's your data:

```
MESSAGEID  USERID   TOUSERID    MESSAGE           TIME
1          1        2           nachricht 1       123
2          1        2           nachricht 2       124
3          2        1           nachricht 3       125
4          3        2           nachricht wrong   1263
5          2        4           nachricht wrong   1261
6          4        1           nachricht sandra  126
```

Comment: But why should the message with the ID of 2 correct? ID 3 is the latest message in the conversation between 1 and 2, thus 3 should be correct?

Comment: I was talking about messageID 3. messageID 3 has a time value of 125 and messageID 2 124.

Comment: I've added your data to my answer. You can see that question 1 and 2 match the first part, with question 2 being the latest, and question 3 and 6 match the second part, with 6 being the latest.

Answer (score 1):

The below works as required:

```
SELECT  m1.*
FROM    Message m1
        LEFT JOIN Message m2
            ON LEAST(m1.toUserID, m1.userID) = LEAST(m2.toUserID, m2.userID)
            AND GREATEST(m1.toUserID, m1.userID) = GREATEST(m2.toUserID, m2.userID)
            AND m2.time > m1.Time
WHERE   m2.MessageID IS NULL
AND (   (m1.toUserID IN (2,4) AND m1.userID = 1)
    OR  (m1.userID IN (2,4) AND m1.toUserID = 1)
    );
```

To simplify how this works, imagine you just wanted the latest message sent by userid 1, rather than having to match the to/from tuples as this adds clutter to the query that doesn't help. To get this I would use:

```
SELECT  m1.*
FROM    Message AS m1
        LEFT JOIN Message AS m2
            ON m2.UserID = m1.UserID
            AND m2.time > m1.time
WHERE   m1.UserID = 1
AND     m2.MessageID IS NULL;
```

So, we are joining similar messages, stipulating that the second message (m2) has a greater time than the first, where m2 is null it means there is not a similar message with a later time, therefore m2 is the latest message.

Exactly the principal has been applied in the solution, but we have a more complicated join to link conversations.

I have used `LEAST` and `GREATEST` in the join, the theory being that since you have 2 members in your tuple `(UserID, ToUserID)`, then in any combination the greatest and the least will be the same, e.g.:

```
From/To |  Greatest | Least |
--------+-----------+-------+
  1, 2  |     2     |   1   |
  2, 1  |     2     |   1   |
  1, 4  |     4     |   1   |
  4, 1  |     4     |   1   |
  4, 2  |     4     |   2   |
  2, 4  |     4     |   2   |
```

As you can see, in similar From/To the greatest and the least will be the same, so you can use this to join the table to itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two parts** of your query in the **following order**:

1. You want the latest outgoing or incoming message for a conversation between two users
2. You want these latest messages for two different pairs of users, i.e. conversations.

So, lets get the latest message for a conversation between UserID a and UserID b:

```
SELECT *
FROM message 
WHERE (toUserID, userID) IN ((a, b), (b, a)) 
ORDER BY message.time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Then you want these to be combined for the two conversations between UserIDs 1 and 2 and UserIDs 1 and 4. This is where the union comes into play (we do not need to check for duplicates, thus we use UNION ALL, thanks to Marcus Adams, who brought that up first).

So a **complete and straightforward solution** would be:

```
(SELECT *
FROM message 
WHERE (toUserID, userID) IN ((2, 1), (1, 2)) 
ORDER BY message.time DESC
LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * 
FROM message 
WHERE (toUserID, userID) IN ((4, 1), (1, 4)) 
ORDER BY message.time DESC
LIMIT 1)
```

And as expected, you get message 3 and 6 in your [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96407/26).